# Why am I getting cv2 error in raspbianOS and not raspberrypi shell

Tags: python

I recently installed and compiled openCV on my raspberrypi.
Now if I use the command `import cv2` in my raspian OS (either in the python shell or the IDE) I get an error

> no module named cv2 found but the same command works in the raspberrypi shell.

How do I resolve this??

- File  "home/pi/Desktop/FR.py",line 2,in module
- import cv2
- File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py",line
  305,in_custom_import
- module=self_original_import(*args,**kw) ImportError:no module named
  'cv2'

Comment: Hi, is there a way you can share the code and the output of the command `python -c 'import cv2'`?

Comment: This command simply executes

Comment: Are you sure it's the same python version? Are you running `python` or `python3/2`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run your code after executing the below command.

**python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python**